# Reference Error: 'Variable_Name' is undefined - HTML5 Canvas Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Background: For a university project I have been tasked with creating a Flappy Bird clone. Originally it worked fine, then as I began adding more images, they stopped loading within Chrome. Firefox was fine (unless I did a fresh reload, but every subsequent reload was fine).

I was making a new 'Sprite' object for each image and within that sprite object's initialiser I would create an Image object and assign the src. I eventually realised this was the problem, so I rearranged my structure like this:

```
var ent_player_img = new Image();

ent_player_img.onload = function()
{
    window.ent_player = new Sprite(ent_player_img);
};

ent_player_img.src = "../images/ent_player.png";
```

I would assign ent_player.img to the new Image object within the constructor. However, this was throwing reference errors within my game loop.

To combat this I put all of the functions in my game loop that called these objects within an if statement.

```
if (typeof ent_player !== undefined)
{
    //Draw image
}
```

And yet I was still getting the errors. Inside the if statement I used a `console.log` saying `typeof ent_player` which returned as `undefined`.

Very puzzled as to why this code was still running and causing issues, I used my debugger of choice (Firebug).

I put a breakpoint on the if statement, however, whenever I step through the code with the debugger it works perfectly. Correct outputs, etc. Then as soon as I try it again without the debugger, same issue.

Can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thank you very much.

Edit: Sprite constructor looks like this:

```
function Sprite(image)
{
    this.img = image;
    this.height = this.img.height;
    this.width = this.img.width;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the `Sprite` constructor look?

Comment: @gxoptg Edited! Shouldn't be anything that could interfere.

Comment: Are you ensuring that the image loaded before your executed that code? Since `ent_player` is defined in an `onload` event for an image, it will only be defined once the loading is complete. Note that the code after will keep executing even when the image is not yet loaded.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Well that's what the if statement is for that checks the typeof that variable. If it's not loaded yet then the functions won't be called and the loop will keep going round until it is defined. It works perfectly as soon as I debug but not normally.

Comment: There is some missing code. Where is the reference error occurring? BTW `window.entPlayer` is the same as `entPlayer` as the window object is the global scope object. You don't use it for `ent_player_img` which is the same `window.ent_player_img` If you wish to use an object in global scope you should define it early and outside all functions with the `var` token. To help keep your code in good order you should consider using the `"use strict;"' directive. It enforces stronger syntax rules, and has the added bonus of running faster code (good for games)

Comment: @Blindman67 I managed to figure it out eventually, it was a combination of me not putting `undefined` in quotation marks and a silly bug where I wasn't storing the return value of my check. Also, I declared the variable with `window` because I was declaring it within a function, so it wouldn't be available to the global scope otherwise. I didn't declare them earlier on just to save space and keep things a bit tidier. I'll look into `use strict` though!